# SharePoint 2013 Split Content database reached maximum threshhold

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sql-server

We have been experiencing slow response from SharePoint 2013 site collection, sometimes the http request timeout.

The content database have exceeded the supported threshold from Microsoft of 4 TB, current DB size is 6,2 TB. The site contains one document library with 6 million pdf files.

We have tried archiving the old files using PowerShell script but the process is very slow.

Is it possible to split the Content DB from SQL, because the custom code is running very slow?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a tool like ShareGate to migrate data out of your SharePoint site in to another that is using a different content database. Looking at the size of your data, this probably won't be a quick process. You could increase the CPU and memory of the SharePoint server, SQL server and the ShareGate migration server to improve speeds. Additionally, using a fast hard drive for the ShareGate server will help e.g. SSD like speeds.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to split the Content DB from SQL

No, it is not possible (from SQL perspective) to split documents within one library to different DBs.
SharePoint itself can only split one site collection from another, but not at library level.
You could only use third party tools or move the content manually.